# scope of a variable in a block of code

Tags: python, c

I am guessing differences in the following two codes. The first one is in **python** and works just fine.Here it is:

```
>>> def foo():
        if 1:
            print "this is working"
            n=6 
        print "the value of n is {0}".format(n)


>>> foo()
this is working
the value of n is 6
```

The second one is in c, i guess the way i want to implement both programs is same.Here it is:

```
void main(){
    if(1){
        printf("this is working");
        int n=9;
    }
    printf("the value of n is %d",n);
}
```

`n` goes `undeclared` in the **c** code while it works good in **python**.
I know that in the **c** code `n` has scope within the `if block`.But why there is no as such scope issue in **python**. Do the variables inside a block `{ }` are stored in different `memory stacks` in **c** while in **python** they are stored in `function's memory stack` ?.Correct me if i am wrong somewhere.
Regards.

Comment: "memory stack" isn't an actual term in either C or Python. There is (conceptually) only one stack per thread in either language, no matter what functions you call or what variables with what scopes you use.

Comment: I suggest reading [PEP 3104](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/#rationale). This is as close as you will get to an answer to your question.

Comment: In your C example the variable n has "block scope" i.e. it does not exist outside of the curly braces

Comment: @unwind, the other question pointed out by you was useful.Thanks for that.But it does not relate totally to my case, have a look again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, a local variable is part of the function's scope. `if` blocks (and other such blocks) do not have their own separate scope.